# How to parse/match a specific frame_system event?

Tags: events, offchain, parse

From the following function I can read the `frame_system` events:

```
let events = frame_system::Pallet::<T>::read_events_no_consensus();
```

the above provides me the following example array:

```
        EventRecord {
            phase: Phase::ApplyExtrinsic(1),
            event: Event::Balances(Event::Withdraw {
                who: d43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d(5 GrwvaEF...),
                amount: 125000107
            }),
            topics: []
        },
        EventRecord {
            phase: Phase::ApplyExtrinsic(1),
            event: Event::SubstrateKitties(Event::Created {
                kitty: [177, 185, 56, 80, 240, 56, 24, 57, 112, 17, 186, 6, 89, 221, 25, 98],
                owner: d43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d(5 GrwvaEF...)
            }),
            topics: []
        },
        EventRecord {
            phase: Phase::ApplyExtrinsic(1),
            event: Event::System(Event::ExtrinsicSuccess {
                dispatch_info: DispatchInfo {
                    weight: 0,
                    class: DispatchClass::Normal,
                    pays_fee: Pays::Yes
                }
            }),
            topics: []
        }
```

I would like to be able to parse/match ONLY the `Event::SubstrateKitties(Event::Created)` events.

I also reviewed the link below and `Shawn Tabrizi` recommendation related to `assert_last_event` use cases:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64199998/converting-between-event-types

However, I still haven't found a proper way to do this. Below is a simplify example of my latest code so far:

````
        #[pallet::hooks]
        impl<T: Config> Hooks<BlockNumberFor<T>> for Pallet<T> {
            /// Block finalization
            fn on_finalize(_n: BlockNumberFor<T>) {
                let events = frame_system::Pallet::<T>::read_events_no_consensus();
        
                events.iter().for_each(|EventRecord { event, .. }| {
                    match event {
                        // What should I write here?? => {
                            log::info("SubstrateKitties event: {:?}", event);
                        },
                        _ => {
                            log::info!("Ignoring system events.");
                        },
                    }                   
                });
            }
        }
    ```
````

Comment: Please note that it's strongly recommended to **NOT** read the event records in the runtime. Events can grow very large (think about there were >20mb blocks on Kusama), and the read operation is very expensive. So when you read the event, you essentially read all the events from the storage at once, and iterate over them one by one. Instead, you can create your own vector storage item to track the event you are interested.

Comment: @h4x3rotab, your are totally right. Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: Can you read all events for a specific block (perhaps in an offchain worker)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code removed in [this](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/commit/8f5b446ee4c1cff407a2888985178cf692166428) PR is exactly what you need to do. Trying to translate it into your case would yield:

```rust
#[pallet::hooks]
impl<T: Config> Hooks<BlockNumberFor<T>> for Pallet<T> {
    fn on_finalize(_n: BlockNumberFor<T>) {
        let events = frame_system::Pallet::<T>::read_events_no_consensus();

        events.iter().for_each(|EventRecord { event, .. }| {
            // try and convert the event into a local event.
            let local_event = <T as Config>::Event::from(event);
            match local_event.try_into() {
                Ok(ev)
                    // this is an event from this pallet, work with it. 
                },
                _ => {
                    // this is an error from some other pallet
                },
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Let's now break down what is happening here:

The top level runtime has an outer event, which is [this type](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/node_runtime/enum.Event.html). As you see, this is just a wrapper for all pallet events. This type implement `TryInto<T>` where `T` is individual pallet events. Example for pallet-balances [here](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/node_runtime/enum.Event.html#impl-TryInto%3CEvent%3CRuntime%2C%20()%3E%3E).

In your code, `frame_system::Pallet::<T>::read_events_no_consensus();` returns the outer event type, which you have to iterate and individually try and convert into your local pallet event.

Comment: NB: `Ok(ev)` has a typo: `Ok(ev) => {` TIA

Answer (score 4):

@kianenigma, thanks for you extended and detailed answer. There was just one small missing piece. I had to setup the `TryInto<Event<Self>>` to the `#[pallet::config]` macro or otherwise your will get a `is not implemented for pallet::Event<_>` error.
Thanks for your support. Great job!

```
    // Configure the pallet by specifying the parameters and types on which it depends.
    #[pallet::config]
    pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
        /// Because this pallet emits events, it depends on the runtime's definition of an event.
        type Event: From<Event<Self>>
            + IsType<<Self as frame_system::Config>::Event>
            + TryInto<Event<Self>>;
```