# How can I access custom pallet Event data in a test?

Tags: pallet, events, testing

I have an Event (`ThingStored`) that is deposited in a public function in my custom pallet.

```rust
#[derive(Encode, Decode, PartialEq, Clone, RuntimeDebugNoBound, TypeInfo, MaxEncodedLen)]
#[scale_info(skip_type_params(T))]
#[codec(mel_bound())]
pub struct Thing<T: Config> {
    pub id: u64,
    // pub creator: AccountOf<T>
}

#[pallet::event]
#[pallet::generate_deposit(pub(super) fn deposit_event)]
pub enum Event<T: Config> {
    ThingStored(Thing<T>, T::AccountId),
}
```

`Thing` contains data that is generated by the pallet (`id`). In my tests, I call the pallet function that stores a thing and emits the event if successful. How can I read the data of the event that was emited?

In this case, I will read the generated `id` from the event in order to make a subsequent call to the pallet's storage (by id).

```rust
#[test]
fn it_works_for_default_value() {
    new_test_ext().execute_with(|| {
        // Dispatch a signed extrinsic.
        assert_ok!(ThingsModule::create_thing(Origin::signed(1)));
        let emitted_stored_thing_event: Event<Test> = <frame_system::Pallet<Test>>::events().pop().expect("Expected at least one EventRecord to be found").event;
        // let stored_thing: Thing;
        // Read pallet storage and assert an expected result.
        assert_eq!(ThingModule::things(thing.id).unwrap().creator, 1);
    });
}
```

Comment: Ah, I bet this will look similar to how it's handle in `hooks` https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/972/2019

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working example of a test using the `pallet-template` from the `substrate-node-template`:

```rust
#[test]
fn stackexchange_question() {
    new_test_ext().execute_with(|| {
        // To emit events, we need to be past block 0
        System::set_block_number(1);
        // Dispatch a signed extrinsic.
        assert_ok!(TemplateModule::do_something(Origin::signed(1), 42));
        System::assert_last_event(crate::Event::SomethingStored(42, 1).into());

        let event_record: frame_system::EventRecord<_, _> = System::events().pop().unwrap();
        let generic_event: crate::mock::Event = event_record.event;
        let pallet_event: crate::Event<Test> = generic_event.try_into().unwrap();

        let (something, who) = match pallet_event {
            crate::Event::SomethingStored(something, who) => (something, who),
            _ => panic!("unexpected error")
        };

        assert_eq!(who, 1);
        // Read pallet storage and assert an expected result.
        assert_eq!(TemplateModule::something(), Some(something));
    });
}
```

Basically, by the time it gets into storage, it is manipulated in a bunch of ways, and I show you how to do all those un-manipulations above.

Comment: This is fantastic. Thank you 